# How to find in mongoose using a field of reference?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Consider I have the following table:

```
const ImageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  url: {
    type: String,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Image", ImageSchema)
```

Another collection that's using the above collection as ref:

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please add a product name"], 
    },
    
    photos: {
      type: [mongoose.Schema.ObjectId],
      ref: "Image",
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
  },
)

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema)
```

And then another collection that's using these collections:

```
const ContainerSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please add a product name"], 
    },
    
    products: {
      type: [mongoose.Schema.ObjectId],
      ref: "Product",
    },

    images: {
      type: [mongoose.Schema.ObjectId],
      ref: "Image",
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
  },
)

module.exports = mongoose.model("Container", ContainerSchema)
```

Using mongoose, How can I query (find) containers using the name of the product rather than the product id?

I mean like I can find containers using the product id this way:

```
const container = await Container.find({product : product_id});
```

But I wish to find containers using the product name. Also, remember these products are being used as an array in a container, how can I find containers using the product names?

Answer (score 2):

The aggregate method could be better to get that values.

Because of Products is an array, we need to use **$elemMatch** or **".$."** tags to search into Products array. So;

```
const container = await Container.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup:{
                from:'products',
                localField:'products',
                foreignField:'_id',
                as:'ProductContainerTable'
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                'ProductContainerTable.$.name' : productName
            },
        }
    ])
```

the $match condition would be created as ;

```
{'ProductContainerTable': {$elemMatch: {name: productName }}}
```

Hope, it's helpful for you.

Comment: Is it possible to use `$search` inside `$lookup`? I'm using Atlas and I'm attempting to search a Ref, too.

Comment: I used $regex in aggregation for searching into the related field. If I need to write it for this question, it would be like; {'ProductContainerTable.$.name': { $regex: searchValue }}. If you mean that, I hope it helps.